# How to catch AccessDeniedException in Spring Boot REST API

Tags: spring, security, spring-boot

I have a simple Spring Boot REST API with 2 endpoints, one is protected one is not. For the one is protected, I want to catch the `AccessDeniedException` and send a 401 rather than the default 500 error. Here is my security configuration:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter{

@Override
public void configure(WebSecurity webSecurity) {
    webSecurity.ignoring().antMatchers("/");
}

@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http
            .exceptionHandling()
            .accessDeniedHandler(new AccessDeniedHandler() {
                @Override
                public void handle(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, org.springframework.security.access.AccessDeniedException accessDeniedException) throws IOException, ServletException {
                    System.out.println("I am here now!!!");
                }
            });

    http
            .addFilterAfter(getSecurityFilter(), FilterSecurityInterceptor.class);
    http
            .sessionManagement()
            .sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS);
    http
            .csrf()
            .disable();
    http
            .authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers("/protected").anonymous();
}

public Filter getSecurityFilter() {
    return new Filter() {
        @Override
        public void init(FilterConfig filterConfig) throws ServletException {
            //do nothing here
        }

        @Override
        public void doFilter(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response, FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException {
            String appKeyHeaderValue = ((HttpServletRequest)request).getHeader("X-AppKey");
            if(appKeyHeaderValue!=null && appKeyHeaderValue.equals("MY_KEY")) {
                chain.doFilter(request,response);
            } else {
                throw new AccessDeniedException("Access denied man");
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void destroy() {

        }
    };
}
```

}

I never see my `I am here now!!!` print statement, what I instead see is the default page

`Whitelabel Error Page
This application has no explicit mapping for /error, so you are seeing this as a fallback.
Tue Jul 25 23:21:15 CDT 2017
There was an unexpected error (type=Internal Server Error, status=500).
Access denied man`

Notice how my `Access denied man` does get printed from when the exception is being thrown.

When I run the project, I also see the following in the console:

`2017-07-25 23:21:14.818  INFO 3872 --- [  restartedMain] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Mapped "{[/error]}" onto public org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity<java.util.Map<java.lang.String, java.lang.Object>> org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.BasicErrorController.error(javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest)
2017-07-25 23:21:14.818  INFO 3872 --- [  restartedMain] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Mapped "{[/error],produces=[text/html]}" onto public org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.BasicErrorController.errorHtml(javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest,javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse)`

Here is how my project structure looks like:

[image]

Comment: can you set status code 401 instead of 'throw new AccessDeniedException("Access denied man")'   in dofilter(.....) method?

Comment: I could try that, but the ultimate goal is to have a class that handles all exceptions, including `AccessDeniedException`

Comment: so you need to handle all exception in a class right?  right a confgiuration class that will extend WebMvcConfigurerAdapter then add this override method:     @Override
 public void configureHandlerExceptionResolvers(List<HandlerExceptionResolver> exceptionResolvers) {
  
  exceptionResolvers.add(new CustomHandlerExceptionResolver());
 }

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As suggested by @Afridi exception occurs before it even reaches controllers, so it has to be handled in filter chain. I suggest to do the following :

```
public class AccessDeniedExceptionFilter extends OncePerRequestFilter {

    @Override
    public void doFilterInternal(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse res, 
                                FilterChain fc) throws ServletException, IOException {
        try {
            fc.doFilter(request, response);
        } catch (AccessDeniedException e) {
         // log error if needed here then redirect
     RequestDispatcher requestDispatcher = 
             getServletContext().getRequestDispatcher(redirecturl);
     requestDispatcher.forward(request, response);

    }
}
```

Add this filter to filter chain  in

```
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
http
....
.addFilterAfter(httpClientFilter(), AccessDeniedExceptionFilter.class)
```

Comment: OK, I will go over the documentation and see if that helps, so far I try do what you suggested and remove the
`.accessDeniedHandler` but that didn't work. I tried adding it back and have my `ControllerAdvice` class implement the `AccessDeniedHandler` and added back the `.accessDeniedHandler` passing my `ControllerAdvice` as an argument and that didn't work either

Comment: I can't figure out how to format in the "response" here, but this his what I have
`@RestController
    public class ProtectedTestController {

    @RequestMapping("/protected")
    public ResponseEntity<String> home() {
        return ResponseEntity.ok("Hello protected");
    }
    }`

Comment: Change to `@ControllerAdvice(annotations=RestController.class)` and try

Comment: Same result, again, I tried to add the `@ControllerAdvice(annotations=RestController.class)` and removed the `implements  AccessDeniedHandler` line and also removed the `.exceptionHandling().accessDeniedHandler(new MyExceptionHandler());` and it didn't work. I also tried to add the `implements  AccessDeniedHandler` to my `MyExceptionHandler` class and add back the `.exceptionHandling().accessDeniedHandler(new MyExceptionHandler());`, no luck

Comment: Exception controller can handle exceptions thrown by either Controller or services not exceptions thrown by filters etc.

Comment: @Afridi you are right, my bad, I did not pay attention to this fact.

Comment: @ElMoreno I have updated answer, please try to implement

Comment: @fg78nc I tried and now got this error: `Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [javax.servlet.Filter]: Factory method 'springSecurityFilterChain' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Cannot register after unregistered Filter class com.example.demo.AccessDeniedExceptionFilter` I will go over the security documentation and try to figure this one out

Comment: Whats does it say in nested exception ?

Comment: Sorry for the late response. The nested exception was basically the same description as I posted above. I will accept your answer but I have moved on from this approach.

Comment: Where does httpClientFilter() come from? which package? Thx.

Comment: httpClientFilter() what is it?

Answer (score 9):

I use a custom class extending `ResponseEntityExceptionHandler` with some annotations.

You just need to create a Class like this:

```
@ControllerAdvice
public class CustomResponseEntityExceptionHandler extends ResponseEntityExceptionHandler {

    @ExceptionHandler(AccessDeniedException.class)
    public final ResponseEntity<ErrorMessage> handleAccessDeniedException(AccessDeniedException ex, WebRequest request) {
        ErrorMessage errorDetails = new ErrorMessage(new Date(), ex.getMessage(), request.getDescription(false));
        return new ResponseEntity<>(errorDetails, HttpStatus.FORBIDDEN);
    }

}
```

In this case the answer will be something like:

```
{
    "timestamp": "2018-12-28T14:25:23.213+0000",
    "message": "Access is denied",
    "details": "uri=/user/list"
}
```

Comment: Why do you use also use @RestController here?

Comment: This answer is wrong. Access denied exceptions are thrown in the security filter chain, _before_ the controller method is reached. They won't be caught by your exception handler as it only catches exceptions thrown by your controller methods.

Comment: this only works when you use method security, i.e. @PreAuthorize annotation on controller class or controller method level and not antMatcher in security config

Comment: AccessDeniedExceptions thrown by filters are translated automatically in 403's by Spring. However, this does not happen when testing using a framework like RestAssured. Then it does end up in the exception handler.